# Create a "drag and clear mask" on android image view

Tags: android, image-processing, view, imageview, touch

Let me explain what is that mean:

First there is two imageview with the same size, the first one is a mask and it is overlap on the second one which is a photo.

The pusdeo layout

```
<RelativeLayout>
<image view  (mask) match parent>
<image view (photo) match parent>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, when the app start it is a whole dark page. The user then start drag on the screen , it like sweep out the mask and show the photo behind the mask. A sample photo is like this:

[image]

Just focus on the top image, it looks like that , there is a mask on top of the photo, only when user drag on screen, it clean the mask and show the photo behind. How to achieve that, do I need using cavans / other library?

Thanks for helping

Comment: yes,  you need a Canvas for that,  and the best option is to extend Drawable or BitmapDrawable

Comment: are there any tutorial / example that I could follow, would you mind to provide some "keywords" that is about this issue(actually I have no idea how to describe this issue)? Thanks for helping

Comment: extend BitmapDrawable and see what happens in draw method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a code sample. The important parts are 1) it uses a customized view that overlaps the image view; 2) it uses a bitmap canvas for the actual drawing (required in order to be able to clear pixels); and 3) the painting uses the special `CLEAR` transfer mode.

## Output:

[image]

## DrawView.java:

```
package com.example.drawingwithmask;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    private Paint bmPaint = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    private Canvas cv = null;
    private Bitmap bm = null;
    private boolean firstTimeThru = true;


    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }


    public void init() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Set everything up the first time anything gets drawn:
        if (firstTimeThru) {
            firstTimeThru = false;

            // Just quickly fill the view with a black mask:
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            // Create a new bitmap and canvas and fill it with a black mask:
            bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            cv = new Canvas();
            cv.setBitmap(bm);
            cv.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            // Specify that painting will be with fat strokes:
            drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(canvas.getWidth() / 15);

            // Specify that painting will clear the pixels instead of paining new ones:
            drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        }

        cv.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0,  0, bmPaint);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        float xPos = event.getX();
        float yPos = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        // Set the starting position of a new line:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
            return true;

        // Draw a line to the ending position:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
            break;

        default:
            return false;
        }

        // Call onDraw() to redraw the whole view:
        invalidate();
        return true;}
}
```

## activity_layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<com.example.drawingwithmask.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/draw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

## MainActivity.java:

package com.example.drawingwithmask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        drawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.draw);
    }
}
```

## Addendum:

Here's a method that can estimate if a certain threshold of mask clearing has been reached. I tested it by calling `checkProgress()` from the `MOTION_MOVE` event case. This might not be the best way or perhaps even a good way, but it does at least provide an estimate at the expense of STEPS^2 (400 as presented) pixel checks.

```
final int STEPS = 20;
final double THRESHOLD = 0.70;

private void checkProgress() {

    int sum = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < bm.getWidth(); x += bm.getWidth() / STEPS)
        for (int y = 0; y < bm.getHeight(); y += bm.getHeight() / STEPS)
            if (bm.getPixel(x, y) != Color.BLACK)
                sum++;

    double progress = (double) sum / (STEPS * STEPS);
    Log.v(TAG, "Cleared: " + progress);

    if (progress >= THRESHOLD)
        Log.i(TAG, "Done!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot really. work great . One last question, are there any way to check the % of the place is draged? For example, if I drag 70% of the whole screen , then I will do something (say, just change to the another image behind the mask)

Comment: I doubt there's any sort of API-based solution to do something that. I suppose you could keep track of the distances that your drags were done and calculate an estimate from that. Or perhaps you could divide your display area into a grid and calculate an estimate based on which grids sections had been drawn.

Comment: I would try the second approach as the first one may have a problem that user slide on the same area up and down and I still count it.

Comment: The cleaning the mask effect is done through setXfermode, so it seems not easy to check how many percentage area is cleaned, I tried to log the width and height in the ACTION_UP but not work as expected, would you mind sharing some idea of it?

Comment: It does not necessary to be accurate, just clean some of the mask , then trigger a toast , thanks a lot

Comment: I'm thinking both of my quick ideas would be much harder than I originally thought. I wasn't considering that the user could change direction within a single drag operation. that means a single operation could theoretically clear the entire mask.

Comment: I sloved the problem, here is the reference.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600956/how-to-get-the-draw-element-size-on-a-cavans

Comment: Thanks a lot. stackoverflow has a lot of talent

Comment: I added a method that does a brute-force check of the mask-clearing progress. Enjoy!

Comment: Oh, I missed your comment. It's kind of funny that my solution is very close to the one you posted. And yes, the poster in the other question is correct that this technique is a simple form of Monte Carlo simulation.