# How to get the draw element size on a cavans?

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, view

[image]

I was working on a "draw with mask" app. When the user drag on the screen , it cleans part of the mask.

I implemented it through cavans and with setXfermode Clear

```
// Specify that painting will be with fat strokes:
drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(canvas.getWidth() / 15);

// Specify that painting will clear the pixels instead of paining new ones:
drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

cv.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
```

The problem is , **how can I get the percentage of space cleaned?, it doesn't necessary to be accurate, just roughly detect when more than half of screen size is clean.** Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to convert your `canvas` in to **bitmap** and count the number of `black pixels` in it. Using simple math you can divide the number of black pixels to the number of pixels in the **canvas** which will give you the percentage of black pixels.

sample [taken from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357246/how-to-get-total-area-covered-while-drawing-path-on-canvas-android):

```
 public float percentTransparent(Bitmap bm) { //pass the converted bitmap of canvas
    final int width = bm.getWidth();
    final int height = bm.getHeight();

    int totalBlackPixels = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            if (bm.getPixel(x, y) == Color.BLACK) {
                totalBlackPixels ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return ((float)totalBlackPixels )/(width * height); //returns the percentage of black pixel on screen

}
```

Comment: Really impressive. This work great. One last question, is it possible to do estimation instead of 1 pixel by 1 pixel? For my case , it don't need accurate

Comment: @user782104 upvote this post if it helps thank you, none that I can think of there is one from the post called `Monte Carlo method ` which is fast rather than counting pixel by pixel